# How do I get this Powershell function to just return the value of $element?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I'm using Powershell Core 6.2.2 and have the following function:

```
function New-JobElement() {
    Param(
        [Parameter()]
        [String]
        $Name,

        # This parameter does nothing yet... Planned for future use
        [Parameter()]
        [String]
        $Value
    )

    [xml] $xml = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument

    [System.Xml.XmlElement] $element = $xml.CreateElement("job", $Name, "my.job.uri")

    if ($null -ne $Value) {
        $element.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode($Value))
    }

    return $element
}
```

When I call the function, the returned object appears to be a `System.Object[]` rather than the expected object.

```
$foo = New-JobElement -Name "foo" -Value "bar"
Write-Host $foo.getType()
```

This writes out the following to the console:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Thus I can't pass this result into something like `XMLDocument.AppendChild()`.

Why is the type changing and how can I get this function to work the way I want to? (That is, returning an XMLElement).

**Update:** How do I get this function just to return `$element`?

Comment: That's not the full function body, is it? Please post code that actually reproduces the issue

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, that is the full function body. That's why I'm confused. What are you expecting to be there that's missing?

Comment: A straggling `$value`, a bare cast or maybe another method call that unexpectedly returns something. Did you previously cast `$foo` to `[object[]]` in the session where you're getting this result? What is the `Length` and contents of `$foo`?

Comment: `Write-Host $foo.GetType()` returns `System.Xml.XmlElement` when I run your code.

Comment: Can't reproduce in PowerShell Core 6.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It appears that there was a bit of code missing in the initial question after all.  I rem'd out the lines causing the problem and neglected to save. I assumed that the problem was still there even after the change which was my initial confusion. That being said, even with the code added back in, I still would expect that an XmlElement would be returned.

Comment: Looks like I had an X/Y Problem. What I really needed to know was how to only return $element. I've updated the question.

I figured it out and left the answer as a comment to Jessen's response.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, the statement linked above does not have the answer to how to prevent this behavior. I have figured out how to do so and have commented as such in Mathias's answer. Please reopen so that the answer can be posted as an answer.

Comment: @JasonThompson Yes, it does. PowerShell functions return *all* non-captured output, which in your case includes the output of `$element.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode($Value))`. Returning multiple objects (the output of `AppendChild()` and `$element`) gives you the array you observed. If you don't want that you MUST suppress ALL output that shouldn't be returned. Please re-read my answer to the other question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ah... Yes. I see it. Thanks for making StackOverflow a better place.  For those who don't feel like clicking and digging, the answer is just to assign it to $null. $null = someFunctionThatReturnsAValue();

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$element.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode($Value))
```

returns the newly appended node.

`$foo` is indeed an array, consisting of the node emitted by [`AppendChild()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netcore-2.2) and the `$element` that you return

Comment: So what you're saying is that the function returns both the result of AppendChild AND the return statement? Strange. How would I go about just returning $element?

Comment: I figured it out. I need to store $element.AppendChild into $null.